# Ensure that a bloc of text will be displayed on the same page

Tags: c#, openxml

I'm generating reports from a `.docx` document using `HtmlToOpenXml`.

I **need** to ensure that a particular html block will be displayed on the **same page**, for example:

```
<p>Video provides a powerful way to help [...]</p>
<br />
<br />
<p>To make your document look professionally [...]</p>
```

I took a look around the web:

- [Open XML Table Header Same page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36439159/open-xml-table-header-same-page)
- [Create page break using OpenXml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2795315/create-page-break-using-openxml)

`<w:pPr><w:keepNext/></w:pPr>` had my attention but I'm not sure that I can put two paragraphs inside a larger one.

I'm aware that it will depend of the font, size and so on but it will not change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use "page-break-inside" style in your first block surrounding content to move it to new page. Then try to keep other blocks small enough to fit page (no matter how hard you will try, if the content is too big, it won't fit on one page). Like in example:

```
<div style="page-break-inside: avoid">
    <p>Video provides a powerful way to help [...]</p>
    <br />
    <br />
    <p>To make your document look professionally [...]</p>
</div>
```

Take a look at documentation here: [CSS page-break-before Property](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_print_pagebb.asp)

Comment: It looks promising, I'll give it a shot

Comment: you may also try to use "page-break-inside: avoid" to keep all wrapper content at single page

Comment: Change your answer to `page-break-inside: avoid;` and I'll accept it :)

Comment: i understand that it worked for you. nice to hear that I helped. Answer edited :)